# Understanding gradient of gradient descent algorithm in Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, gradient-descent

I'm trying to figure out the python code for multivariate gradient descent algorithm, and have found several several implementations like this:

```
import numpy as np

# m denotes the number of examples here, not the number of features
def gradientDescent(x, y, theta, alpha, m, numIterations):
    xTrans = x.transpose()
    for i in range(0, numIterations):
        hypothesis = np.dot(x, theta)
        loss = hypothesis - y
        cost = np.sum(loss ** 2) / (2 * m)
        print("Iteration %d | Cost: %f" % (i, cost))
        # avg gradient per example
        gradient = np.dot(xTrans, loss) / m
        # update
        theta = theta - alpha * gradient
    return theta
```

From the definition of gradient descent, the expression of gradient descent is:
[image: [\frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^m(h_\theta(x^{(i)})-y^{(i)})x_j^{(i)}]]

However, in numpy, it is being calculated as: `np.dot(xTrans, loss) / m`
Can someone please explain how we have got this numpy expression ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code is actually very straightforward, it would be beneficial to spend a bit more time to read it.

- `hypothesis - y` is the first part of the square loss' gradient (as a vector form for each component), and this is set to the `loss` variable. The calculuation of the hypothesis looks like it's for linear regression.
- `xTrans` is the transpose of `x`, so if we dot product these two we get the sum of their components' products.
- we then divide by `m` to get the average.

Other than that, the code has some python style issues. We typically use `under_score` instead of `camelCase` in python, so for example the function should be `gradient_descent`. More legible than java isn't it? :)